# Remove duplicate values from list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have list of dictionaries with nested structure. I need to remove all duplicate values. I'm newbie in Python and can't solve this task. Anyone can help me?

My list looks like:

```
[  
   {  
      "task_id":123,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "url":"site.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"another_site.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"site1.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "task_id":456,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "url":"site3.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"site.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "task_id":789,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "url":"site7.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"site9.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"site.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to set site.com only once. If any value of url is duplicated - exclude it from dict.

As result: 
task 123 with 3 dicts in results
task 456 with 1 dict in results (exclude site.com)
task 789 with 2 dict in results (exclude site.com)

Desired output should looks like:

```
[  
   {  
      "task_id":123,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "url":"site.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"another_site.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"site1.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "task_id":456,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "url":"site3.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "task_id":789,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "url":"site7.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         },
         {  
            "url":"site9.com",
            "date":"04.18.2019"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: The `url` is there for different keys, Could you add a desired output as well?

Comment: Is your nested values recursive (ie variable depth of tree, so a dict can contain array of dicts and so on) or constant depth?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow It's constant depth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let `results` to be your array.

```
u = set()
final = []
for dict in results:
   for res in dict["results"]:
      if res["url"] not in u:
         u.add(res["url"])
         final.append(res)
print(final)
```

Comment: @NatalyFirstova you may accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: @findoutislamnow can you please post the entire thing from  beginning import to Print

Comment: @mohan111 This is not needing any imports. Just paste this code after your array retrieval.

Comment: I'm getting errors for that array retrieval can you please post me the proper as I'm  new to  python @FindOutIslamNow

Comment: @mohan111 Take the array from the question copy-paste `e.g. results = [..` paste here, then paste the answer code

Comment: thanks @FindOutIslamNow I can execute now thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = [{'task_id': 123, 'results': [{'url': 'site.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}, {'url': 'another_site.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}, {'url': 'site1.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}]}, {'task_id': 456, 'results': [{'url': 'site3.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}, {'url': 'site.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}]}, {'task_id': 789, 'results': [{'url': 'site7.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}, {'url': 'site9.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}, {'url': 'site.com', 'date': '04.18.2019'}]}]
new_d = [{**a, 'results':[c for c in a['results'] if all(c not in b['results'] for b in d[:i])]} for i, a in enumerate(d)]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "task_id": 123,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "site.com",
            "date": "04.18.2019"
        },
        {
            "url": "another_site.com",
            "date": "04.18.2019"
        },
        {
            "url": "site1.com",
            "date": "04.18.2019"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "task_id": 456,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "site3.com",
            "date": "04.18.2019"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "task_id": 789,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "site7.com",
            "date": "04.18.2019"
        },
        {
            "url": "site9.com",
            "date": "04.18.2019"
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 people = {
          1: {'name': 'John',},
              2: {'name': 'Marie'},
          3: {'name': 'Ann',},
          4: {'name': 'John'},
     }
print(people)
unique = {}
for key, value in people.items(): 
       if value not in unique.values(): 
          unique[key] = value
print(unique)
```

try these

Comment: This does not solve the problem stated. Please go through the problem posted in the question.